# Uncaught ReferenceError: is not definedVM1299:1 (anonymous function)

Tags: javascript

help me out to see where this error is because all i get is this error when i try to run this code Uncaught ReferenceError:  is not definedVM1299:1 (anonymous function)

```
function delete_regno(regno)
{
     if(confirm('Sure To Remove This Vehicle?'))
     {
        window.location.href='delete.php?delete_regno='+regno;
     }
}

<a href="javascript:delete_regno(<?php echo $row['regno']; ?>)" class="table-actions-button ic-table-delete">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose `regno` is not an `integer`, so you missed the `'`

Try this out:

```
<a href="javascript:delete_regno('<?php echo $row['regno']; ?>')"
```